# ASCII text art logo not displaying properly in PHP. (noob coder)

Tags: php, text, ascii

I'm trying to add this ascii art logo for my YOURLS website index.php:

```
<pre style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace"><?php echo 

$asciiart; ?/></pre>

        $asciiart = '
__/\\\\____________/\\\\__/\\\________/\\\_____/\\\\\\\\\_____/\\\________/\\\________/\\\\____________/\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\_\n        
 _\/\\\\\\________/\\\\\\_\/\\\_____/\\\//____/\\\\\\\\\\\\\__\///\\\____/\\\/________\/\\\\\\________/\\\\\\_\/\\\///////////__\n        
  _\/\\\//\\\____/\\\//\\\_\/\\\__/\\\//______/\\\/////////\\\___\///\\\/\\\/__________\/\\\//\\\____/\\\//\\\_\/\\\_____________\n       
   _\/\\\\///\\\/\\\/_\/\\\_\/\\\\\\//\\\_____\/\\\_______\/\\\_____\///\\\/____________\/\\\\///\\\/\\\/_\/\\\_\/\\\\\\\\\\\_____\n      
    _\/\\\__\///\\\/___\/\\\_\/\\\//_\//\\\____\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\_______\/\\\_____________\/\\\__\///\\\/___\/\\\_\/\\\///////______\n    
     _\/\\\____\///_____\/\\\_\/\\\____\//\\\___\/\\\/////////\\\_______\/\\\_____________\/\\\____\///_____\/\\\_\/\\\_____________\n    
      _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_\/\\\_____\//\\\__\/\\\_______\/\\\_______\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\_\/\\\_____________\n   
       _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_\/\\\______\//\\\_\/\\\_______\/\\\_______\/\\\________/\\\_\/\\\_____________\/\\\_\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\_\n  
        _\///______________\///__\///________\///__\///________\///________\///________\///__\///______________\///__\///////////////__\n'
 asciiart;
```

but it breaks the index.php! it just shows me a blank screen... What am I doing wrong?

this is the working source code from my index.php before i tried to add in the ascii text logo...

[pastebin of working source code of my modified YOURLS website index.php](https://pastebin.com/QwuR4S7h)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it reversed.
First assign the $asciiart variable,
and after it echo out.

so your code shoud be:

```
<?php $asciiart = '......'; ?>
<pre style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace"><?php echo 
$asciiart; ?></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing that. I added it to the index.php but it breaks the file and I only get a blank screen. How can I make a new index.php from scratch to test this code on its own in php?

Comment: i tried testing the code on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ but it doesn't work :( it gives me "Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected"

Comment: try now,  I mistyped the php closing tag,  '?>'
if you want a index.php working put around html tags.
Copy code from here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp, and put the php code in the body.